# How to add checkbox if i fetch the record from Database

Tags: java

1. I want add checkbox front of my record, when i fetch the record from
   database.Plz check my code your automatically know what i want

---

1. Class Name:-AddAccountDao.Java

   ```
     public class AddAccountDao {
     public static List<AddAccount> view(){
       List <AddAccount> list=new ArrayList<>();
       try{
           Connection con=getCon();
           PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM adminaccount");
           ResultSet rst=pst.executeQuery();
           while(rst.next()){
               AddAccount ad=new AddAccount();
               ad.setId(rst.getInt(1));
               ad.setName(rst.getString(2));
               ad.setPassword(rst.getString(3));
               ad.setEmail(rst.getString(4));
               ad.setContact(rst.getString(5));
               list.add(ad);
           }
           con.close();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
       return list;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Class Name:-AdminViewAccount

   ```
       public class AdminViewAccount extends JFrame{
       static AdminViewAccount frame;
   public AdminViewAccount(){
           List<AddAccount> list=AddAccountDao.view();
           int size=list.size();
           String data[][]=new String[size][6];
           int row=0;
       for(AddAccount ad:list){
               data[row][1]=String.valueOf(ad.getId());
               data[row][2]=ad.getName();
               data[row][3]=ad.getPassword();
               data[row][4]=ad.getEmail();
               data[row][5]=ad.getContact();
               row++;
           }
           String columnName[]=                                                {"Select","ID","Name","Password","Email","Contact No."};

           JTable t=new JTable(data,columnName);
           JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(t);
           add(sp);
           setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
           setBounds(100,100,800,400);
               }
           public static void main(String[] args) {
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

           @Override
           public void run() {
               try{
                   frame=new AdminViewAccount();
                   frame.setVisible(true);
               }
               catch(Exception e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
           }
   }
   ```
3. Class Name:-AddAccount

   ```
   public class AddAccount {
   private int id;
   private String name,password,email,contact;
   public AddAccount(){}
       public AddAccount(String name,String password,String email,String     contact){
           super();
           this.name=name;
           this.password=password;
           this.email=email;
           this.contact=contact;
       }
       public void setId(int id){
           this.id=id;
       }
       public int getId(){
           return id;
       }
       public void setName(String name){
           this.name=name;
       }
       public String getName(){
           return name;
       }
       public void setPassword(String password){
           this.password=password;
       }
       public String getPassword(){
           return password;
       }
       public void setEmail(String email){
           this.email=email;
       }
       public String getEmail(){
           return email;
       }
       public void setContact(String contact){
           this.contact=contact;
       }
       public String getContact(){
           return contact;
       }
   }
   ```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shmm9.jpg]

Comment: And the reason you unaccepted the answer was???

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a custom TableModel that uses your TableModel and adds a check box column at the start of the table:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class CheckBoxWrapperTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();

    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private String columnName;

    public CheckBoxWrapperTableModel(DefaultTableModel model, String columnName)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.columnName = columnName;

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
            checkBoxes.add( Boolean.FALSE );
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column)
    {
        return (column > 0) ? model.getColumnName(column - 1) : columnName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return model.getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return model.getColumnCount() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
    {
        if (column > 0)
            return model.getValueAt(row, column - 1);
        else
        {
            Object value = checkBoxes.get(row);
            return (value == null) ? Boolean.FALSE : value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        if (column > 0)
            return model.isCellEditable(row, column - 1);
        else
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
    {
        if (column > 0)
            model.setValueAt(value, row, column - 1);
        else
        {
            checkBoxes.set(row, (Boolean)value);
        }

        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        return (column > 0) ? model.getColumnClass(column - 1) : Boolean.class;
    }

    public void removeRow(int row)
    {
        checkBoxes.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        model.removeRow(row);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        //  Create the table with check marks in the first column

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            model.setValueAt("" + i, i, 0);
        }

        CheckBoxWrapperTableModel wrapperModel = new CheckBoxWrapperTableModel(model, "Select");
        JTable table = new JTable(wrapperModel);

        //  Add button to delete selected rows

        JButton button = new JButton( "Delete Selected Rows" );
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                for (int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Boolean selected = (Boolean)table.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    System.out.println(selected + " : " + i);

                    if (selected)
                    {
                        wrapperModel.removeRow(i);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
        frame.add( button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Or the other approach, since you are just copying the data to the TableModel is to just add an extra column when you copy the data:

```
data[row][0] = Boolean.FALSE; // added
data[row][1]=String.valueOf(ad.getId());
```

You would then also need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your TableModel to return `Boolean.class` for the first column as demonstrated in the TableModel above.